# app crashes in the middle of printing contact names and numbers

Tags: swift3, cncontact

This is my code, my app crashes in the middle of printing the data, without an error message in the log. it prints almost 30 people and then crashes, with this message on the line of code that crashed:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode =.....)
```

I will mark the line of code with //CRASH where this message appears on in my code:

```
import UIKit
import Contacts
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for cont in contacts {
        print(cont.givenName)
        let num = ((cont.phoneNumbers.first?.value)! as CNPhoneNumber).stringValue //CRASH
        print(num)
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

lazy var contacts: [CNContact] = {
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    let keysToFetch = [
        CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
        CNContactEmailAddressesKey,
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
        CNContactImageDataAvailableKey,
        CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey] as [Any]

    // Get all the containers
    var allContainers: [CNContainer] = []
    do {
        allContainers = try contactStore.containers(matching: nil)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching containers")
    }

    var results: [CNContact] = []

    // Iterate all containers and append their contacts to our results array
    for container in allContainers {
        let fetchPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsInContainer(withIdentifier: container.identifier)

        do {
            let containerResults = try contactStore.unifiedContacts(matching: fetchPredicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
            results.append(contentsOf: containerResults)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching results for container")
        }
    }

    return results
}()
```

}

I thought I may be unwrapping nil but its not the case since it is not an optional (I tried to unwrap it in a safe way and the compiler says it is not an optional type).

Comment: When it crashes, examine the value of `cont.phoneNumbers.first?.value` in the debugger (or just print it).

Comment: Do you mean to print it without the casting and .stringing it?

Comment: Yes, just to see if there's anything suspicious about the one that crashes vs. the ones that are OK.

Comment: Great idea, will update in 5 minutes

Comment: @PhillipMills , yup, that one is a nil. I am suprised I didn't get the message that I tried unwrapping a nil. I guess that is a contact without a number field?

Comment: Probably...I simply assume that any time I see `!` that it will turn out to be the cause of something bad.

Comment: true, thanks. If you want to post this as an answer I will happily accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

The problem turns out to be the forced unwrapping of `cont.phoneNumbers.first?.value` since it will be nil if there are no phone numbers (and therefore no first to evaluate).